# Typesafe call some function from object of functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to create an object of functions(all functions have 1 parameter).
And make another function that can typesafe pass parameters from the outside call to one of the functions from an object.

```
const double = (v: number) => v * v
const concat = (v: string) => v + v

const functions = {
    double, concat
}

const execute = <T extends keyof typeof functions>
    (key: T, param: Parameters<typeof functions[T]>[0]) => {

    functions[key](param) // here i can't match param type to function argument type, and getting an error

}

execute('double', 'str') // here everything is fine i get correct TypeError
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiArgIwDYFMYF4YAoBuAXDGIgLbLoBOAlNgHwz4wBUTAUKJLF8AIawcBYtCoBLMAHM6WRswDUHTuGgwAZojDAoYldhgBvdjBPwkadABoYvAewC%207ZdxjoAHumCIomHAB4AFVc3HzA4CBgAa3QATxA1GCgYgAd0ePVNbV1IemNTXGiY4gDrZL4qPjJiAAVyyvQfKgg-JNT0jS0dFQBtAIBdem6ABj6ZRiM8kw6snsK%203DKKshpJmAcnd09vdFwAcgQUDF3rXdFdmiA)

How to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assert that **functions[key]** takes argument of type **param** so that TS gets confirmed that function gets correct param type all the time at runtime.

```
const double = (v: number) => v * v
const concat = (v: string) => v + v

const functions = {
    double, concat
}


const execute = <T extends keyof typeof functions>
    (key: T, param: Parameters<typeof functions[T]>[0]) => {

    (functions[key] as (v:typeof param)=>typeof param)(param)
} 

execute('double', 5)
execute('double', 'ram) // error
execute('concat', 'ram')
execute('concat', 5) // error
```

Comment: By "make sure", you mean "assert".  You're telling -- not asking -- the compiler.

Comment: Why do you think so? We are always sure  that we are getting correct param type.  Does it break in any condition?

Comment: @IvanTarasov there's nothing better, unfortunately.  We'd need something like [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#25879](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25879) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to allow the compiler to verify safety here.  You could jump through other hoops but a type assertion is the easiest, I think

Comment: I got it, thank you guys
it just seems almost like ts-ignore for me